# Spotify Android SDK - how to refresh the Player object after an hour

Tags: java, android, spotify

I am using the Spotify Android SDK version spotifysdk-1.0.0-beta8.aar. I have a valid OAuth token which I am refreshing each hour successfully. This is how I am getting the Spotify Player Object initially

```
mPlayer = Spotify.getPlayer(playerConfig, this, new Player.InitializationObserver() {
    @Override
    public void onInitialized(Player player) {
        player.addConnectionStateCallback(JukeSpotDashboardActivity.this);
        player.addPlayerNotificationCallback(JukeSpotDashboardActivity.this);
        player.login(utils.getPreferenceValue(getString(R.string.spotify_access_token)));
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
        Log.e(JukeSpotDashboardActivity.class.getName(),
            "Could not initialize player: " + throwable.getMessage());
    }
});
```

At the end of each hour the access token gets refreshed and stored in the shared preferences. How do you guys suggest I use the new access token in the same mPlayer object so that which ever song is being streamed currently won't get stopped and I won't need to recreate this Spotify player object?

I know there is the

```
mPlayer.login(accessToken);
```

function, but it did not work when I got the new accessToken and relogged in. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Once logged in, your application will be able to stream until the application is stopped, the network connection is lost, or the user's premium account has ended. (There may be other events as well.) This means that you don't need to update the Player object with the refreshed access token to continue streaming.

Note that if you're making any other requests using an access token such as adding a track to a playlist, the access token must be updated in whatever tool you're using to perform the request. For example, if you're using kaaes' excellent [Spotify Web API client for Android](https://github.com/kaaes/spotify-web-api-android), you'd need to get a new `SpotifyService` instance based on the refreshed access token.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But suppose I want to play a track after an hr and I have the refreshed access token with me, how do I update the mPlayer object to use this new access token?

Comment: No, you don't need to create a new Player object with the new access token. You could theoretically stream a lot longer than the access token's expiry time given without updating mPlayer.

Comment: Well, what I have noticed now is the streaming stops after an hour.

Comment: What happens when the player stops? Callbacks? The correct behaviour is that you should be able to continue playing, anything else is considered a bug.